# Missing DNS manage console in RSAT Windows 10 after 1709 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709

After Windows 10 Pro release upgrade from `1703` to `1709` i reinstall RSAT from [Microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520&40ddd5bd-f9e7-49a6-3526-f86656931a02=True) (after releas upgrade it disappear) and found that DNS management console is missing.

Is there any way to get `dnsmgmt.msc` console on `1709`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an known issue, and there's a work around for [it](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/770uf4/new_1709_rsat_tools_doesnt_include_dns_manager/) shared on Reddit.

Basically use the [Server 2016 RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520&40ddd5bd-f9e7-49a6-3526-f86656931a02=True).

Comment: Please refer to https://serverfault.com/a/891412/81294 instead (which includes a link to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055558/rsat-missing-dns-server-tool-in-windows-10-version-1709).